# solid text on transparent div on image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reproduce this image, with HTML and CSS, but I'm not sure how to place solid images on translucent divs on top of an image.  There's one up top and on bottom. And I need a table of these.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/house.png

**Response to comment**: `<table>` is my lazy way of forcing all the divs to be the same width (and the image).  I guess I need to take the text **out** of the divs and place them, which I also had a hard time doing.  Then I worried if use resizes the browser.

Here's what I got so far on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/32szC/).  Here's the HTML code:

```
<table><tr><td>
     <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/samplehouse.png">
     <div class="address"><p class="address">804 Rolfe</p></div>
     <div class='desc'>
         <span class='l'>2 Bedrooms</span>
         <span class='r'>$2100</span>
     </div>   
</td></tr></table>
```

Here's the CSS file:

```
div.address { 
    width:100%; 
    height:20px;
    background-color:#000000; 
    opacity:0.5;
}

span.l{
    width:50%;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:75%;
    float:left;
    margin-top:0px;
}
span.r{
    width:50%;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:75%;
    float:right;
    margin-top:0px;
}

div.desc { 
    width:100%; 
    height:20px;
    background-color:#000000; 
    opacity:0.5;
}

p.address{
    font-family:Helvetica;
    height:20px;
    opacity:1;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Hint 1: Drop the table. Unless you're coding up tabular data, there's no use for them. Hint 2: At some point, you're going to start wondering why your text is also see-through. "I only want the background to be see-through. Not the text." Opacity affects an element **AND** its children. You can use the opacity parameter of RGBA color to achieve what you want: background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);

Answer (score 2):

The fiddle with markup cleaned and css refactored: http://jsfiddle.net/32szC/4/

Anyway take into *serious* consideration the suggestion to not use tables for layout purpose: so I made the css working even if you choose to remove the table structure at all using `display: inline-block` on the `.wrapper` element (see http://jsfiddle.net/32szC/7/)

**HTML**

```
 <table>
 <tr><td>
     <div class="wrapper">
         <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/samplehouse.png" />
         <div class="address"><span class="address">804 Rolfe</span></div>
         <div class='desc'><span>2 Bedrooms</span><span>$2100</span></div>
    </div>
 </td></tr></table>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    height:20px;
}

div.address { top: 0; }
div.desc { bottom: 0; }

span {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:75%;
    color: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    line-height:20px;
}

.address span {
   display: block;
}

.desc span {
    width:50%;   
    float: left;
}
.desc span + span {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt, it includes the shadow border around the image: http://jsfiddle.net/katychuang/2R3hk/

Removed tables to use div. The outer class is "item"

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="address">
      <span>804 Rolfe</span>
  </div>
    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/samplehouse.png">
   <div class='desc'><span class='l'>2 Bedrooms</span><span class='r'>$2100</span></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS. It is good to specify the individual widths for .item and .item img, to get them to line up rather than using 100%

```
.address {  
    height:20px;
    width:inherit;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
    font-family:Helvetica;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:500;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    padding-top:5px;
}

span.l{
    width:50%;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:75%;
    float:left; 
}
span.r{
    width:50%;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:75%;
    float:right; 
}

.desc { 
    width: inherit;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);              
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 500;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.item img {width:250px}

.item {
  position:relative;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* FF3.5+ */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* Opera 10.5, IE 9.0 */
      filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=10px, OffY=10px, Color='#888'); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=10px, OffY=10px, Color='#888')"; /* IE8 */
}

body {background-color:#EEEEEE;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my interpretation of what you should be doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/32szC/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="product">
    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/samplehouse.png">
    <span class="address">804 Rolfe</span>
    <div class='desc'>
        <span class='left'>2 Bedrooms</span>
        <span class='right'>$2100</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product {
    width: 272px;
    height: 220px;
    position: relative;
}

.product img {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.address, .desc { 
    display: block;
    width: 252px; /* 272px */
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
}

.desc { 
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.desc .left {
    float: left;
}

.desc .right {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need some negative margins. I would place the address above the image and the description below it. Then something as simple as `margin-bottom: -20px` will overlap the address over the image.

I made the appropriate changes here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfqJn/1/)